# Can I get HCWP to display content by date

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a document library with videos and would like for them to be displayed in a Highlighted Content Web Part according to the date they were recorded. I have added a column to my library called Air Date but when I add the HCWP and select for the videos to be displayed by recent they are displayed by the modified date column rather than by the Air date column.

is there any way I can get it to do this? I am new to SharePoint and am not a developer so any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

See: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/how-to-sort-highlighted-content-by-date-created/m-p/3721482

By default, the HCWP sorts by the "Modified" date column. Heres a workaround highlighted above.

1. Go to your document library and create a new view that is filtered to your active column and sorted by the "Created" Date descending.
2. Switch that view to "Tile" mode and save it as "New Documents" or something like that.
3. Then go back to your page with the "Highlighted Content Webpart" and remove that webpart from your page.
4. Insert the "Document Library Webpart" and select your document library and your new view.
5. Deselect "Show command bar" and "Show See all button"